# Limit Spreadsheet Access to Scripts

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm attempting to create a poor-man's ticketing system through the use of Google Sheets and bound scripts, but I don't know of any way that I can limit interaction with the spreadsheets to the scripts attached to buttons.  I want to be able to share this sheet and have other users interact via a guided process triggered by my buttons/scripts, so as to avoid corrupting/losing information on the sheet due to carelessness.

At first I thought that I could just protect the sheet ranges that I didn't want damaged and be able to give access via the scripts, but that sadly is not the case.

Ultimately the question is, how can I use scripts to access a protected range with permissions as a viewer only.

Answer (score 0):

you dont want to do it that way.

easiests is to deploy as webapp running as you. they use the webapp instead of pressing buttons or menu items.

to still use buttons/menus/sidebars it is possible but with more steps. you would need to publish a contentService as webapp  (anonymous) and use urlFetch into the service to make thoae changes. not secure because curious users could find that service url in code and use it for bad purposes without traceability.